# Mirroring a section of the document

Tags: packages, reflection

I am working on a paper and I need to mirror a whole section in a page (which is the solution of a puzzle, so the reader needs a mirror in order to read it and there are *no spoilers*).

I'm about to use *images*, *graphs*, *charts* and *text* as well as other *visual tweaks* in the section so I need a tool that **mirrors** whatever I use **without interfering**.

I tried the following code with some text but it doesn't work as expected and it seems to overflow the `\hbox`. The section is pretty big so I would love to use something like `\begin{reflection} .... \end{reflection}`.

```
\reflectbox{
    The first step for the solution of this problem would be to write the recursive
    functions associated with both requests. This is a trivial task but it's necessary
    in order to better understand how they can eventually be manipulated and optimised.
    Focusing on the first problem, the recursive function should be equivalent to this:
    # Other stuff
    # Images, Charts, Code, Whatever.
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\reflectbox` is like `\mbox` so all on one line, you want

```
\noindent\reflectbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
    The first step for the solution of this problem would be to write the recursive
    functions associated with both requests. This is a trivial task but it's necessary
    in order to better understand how they can eventually be manipulated and optimised.
    Focusing on the first problem, the recursive function should be equivalent to this:
...
}}
```